# Removing everything after the second "_" but keeping other columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to format the family IDs on a [fam file](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#fam) whose sample and family IDs are the same, and coded in the following way:

Continent_Breed_Ind-ID

The idea would be to transform column 1 into something that only contains continent+breed, but keeping the other columns.

Mock dataset:

```
Continent1_Breed1_Ind-ID1 Continent1_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
Continent1_Breed2_Ind-ID2 Continent1_Breed2_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -0
Continent2_Breed1_Ind-ID1 Continent2_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
```

Desired outcome:

```
Continent1_Breed1 Continent1_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
Continent1_Breed2 Continent1_Breed2_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -0
Continent2_Breed1 Continent2_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
```

I have tried using sed as follows:

```
sed -r 's/_[^_]*//2g' file.fam
```

But that only gives me the first column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: `sed 's/_[^_]* / /' file`

Comment: That one changes the second column and removes columns 3,4 and 5.

Comment: No it doesn't change. Are you using `g` flag?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Without the flag works as desired. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `plink` which is one of tags you have used

Comment: I'm trying to reformat a `plink` file so that family names are coded properly. I added that tag since I'm sure more experienced users of `plink` have encountered this issue several times and would be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this simple `sed` command:

```bash
sed 's/_[^_]* / /' file

Continent1_Breed1 Continent1_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
Continent1_Breed2 Continent1_Breed2_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -0
Continent2_Breed1 Continent2_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
```

[**Online Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/Jv0QHu)

Here:

- `_[^_]*` : Matches `_` followed by 0 or more non-`_` characters followed by a space
- We replace this match by a space to get the space between first and second column back

PS: Note that there is no global flag used here.

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `sed` command. Using `-E` option to ERE(extended regular expression) here.

```
sed -E 's/^([^_]*)(_[^_]*)_[^[:space:]]+(.*$)/\1\2\3/' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk` using `match` function of it with capturing group capability try following:

```
awk 'match($0,/^([^_]*)(_[^_]*)_[^[:space:]]+(.*$)/,arr){print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> gawk 'sub("_[^_]+$",_,$!_)_'
> mawk 'sub("_[^_]+ "," ")_'
> ```

```
Continent1_Breed1 Continent1_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
Continent1_Breed2 Continent1_Breed2_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -0
Continent2_Breed1 Continent2_Breed1_Ind-ID1 0 0 0 -9
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_/\n/2;s/\n\S*//' file
```

Replace the second `_` by a newline and then remove the newline and any non-white space following it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
awk '{sub(/_[^_]*$/, "", $1)}1' file > newfile
sed 's/^\([^_ ]*_[^_ ]*\)_[^_ ]*/\1/' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo #1](https://ideone.com/9LeaY2) and [demo #2](https://ideone.com/fNNmr6).

*Details*:

- The `awk` solution finds and removes the first occurrence of a `_` char and then zero or more chars other than `_` till end of string (with `sub(/_[^_]*$/, "", $1)`) in the first field, and `1` prints the result
- The sed solution finds:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\([^_ ]*_[^_ ]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1` in RHS refers to this value): zero or more chars other than space and `_`, and underscore and then again zero or more chars other than space and `_`
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[^_ ]*` - zero or more chars other than space and `_`.

And the match is replaced with Group 1 value.